# Probability of outcome is $a^n$

Tags: statistics, biology

I've been reading a biology textbook, and it's stated that

> If the probability of an outcome is indicated by $a^n$, this means that $n+1$ independent events, each occurring randomly and with comparable probability per unit of time, must take place before the ultimate outcome--in this case a diagnosed tumor--is achieved.

I've been trying to figure out why this is, because I thought that the number of independent events would be $n$. For example, the probability of all heads in a coin flipping trial of flipping $n$ coins is $0.5^n$, that means that n independent events (each coin flip) have happened. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advanced for your help!

Comment: I think more context is required.  You (or the text) appear to be using $n$  in two different ways. What is the relation between "outcome" and "events"  and "ultimate outcome" here?

Comment: It is hard to exactly identify what it is that they are talking about without full context, but it appears as though they are modeling being diagnosed with a tumor as a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).  For your coin metaphor, this would be flipping $n$ coins *in sequence* and the first several appearing heads (healthy diagnosis) while the very last coin turns up tails (tumor diagnosis).  If that is the correct interpretation, I'd have expected them to write the probability as $a^n(1-a)$ instead.

Comment: It's most likely a typo - did you check the errata? I am pretty confident that it should actually read as $n-1$-independent events etc. (for context it might also be a good idea to give the reference of this statement)

Comment: There isn't much more context then that. The previous paragraph reads:

Epidemiologists have developed formulas that predict the frequency of various cancers as a function of age. These formulas indicate that, depending upon the cancer type, disease incidence (the rate at which the disease is diagnosed) and mortality rates occur as a function of a^4 to a^7 , where a represents the age of patients at initial diagnosis. 

Weinberg, Robert A.. The Biology of Cancer, Second Edition (Page 440).

Comment: @JMoravitz: If $a$ is the very small probability of diagnosis then unfortunately $a^n \approx a^n(1-a)$  might be a "good enough" approx for many biologists (and referees of bio journals). For example, if $a = .01, n = 4,$ then in R, `a = .01; n = 4; a^n; a^n*(1-a)` returns `1e-08` and `9.9e-09`.

Comment: @JMoravitz The specific thing they are talking about is the development of cancer. Many different genes need to be mutated for a cell growth to become malignant. Each of these mutations can be considered an independent event. They are trying to describe how you can "count" how many independent mutations occur by looking at the rate that people develop cancer.